# How to edit the time remaining every 10 seconds in an embed in discord.py v1.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is my code -

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveaway(ctx, duration: int, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, prize: str):
    giveaway_embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{str(prize)}",
                          description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\n"
                                      f"**React with :tada: to enter!**"
                                      f"Time Remaining: {duration} seconds",
                          color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,)
    embed_send = await channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=giveaway_embed)
    await embed_send.add_reaction("")
    #Every 10 seconds I want to change the Time Remaining: field
```

I want to edit the embed every 5 seconds until the giveaway ends, I cannot quite figure out how to do it, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a FYI... you can probably do this without much issue for the most part but if you have enough giveaways running you will probably run into some serious rate limiting issues.

Comment: No I will only have 2 giveaways running at max.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait 10 seconds, you should use [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), then, there's a [`Message.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit) method:

```py
from discord import Embed, TextChannel
from asyncio import sleep

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveaway(ctx, duration: int, channel: TextChannel, *, prize: str):
    embed = Embed(title=prize,
                  description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\n"
                              f"**React with :tada: to enter!**"
                              f"Time Remaining: {duration} seconds",
                  color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,)

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    while duration:
        await sleep(10)
        duration -= 10
        embed.description = f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention}\n**React with :tada: to enter!**\nTime Remaining: {duration} seconds"
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)

    await ctx.send("Giveaway is over!")
```

PS: I've imported `TextChannel` and `Embed` so I replaced `discord.TextChannel` and `discord.Embed`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying to figure this out since 2 days, Finally my giveaway command is complete. I guess it was really worth posting this on stack overflow !